# Customize profile Magento 2 Performance Toolkit

Tags: magento2, performance, install-script, regenerate

I want to generate 100000 products for performance testing. I using the magento performance toolkit and try to edit setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/large.xml from 30000 to 100000 products. But it has not applied when run command:
bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /var/www/html/magento2/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/large.xml
There is anyway to customize a profile?